# SQL query to get top 10 of a new column generated by SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, top-n

I have a query that looks like so:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS Total
FROM Sales  
WHERE Date = " + ddItems.SelectedItem + "
GROUP BY Name
```

How can I show the top 10 totals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL the number of rows can be limited with the LIMIT clause, so you can add this to your query to get the top 10:

```
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added that after my GROUP BY, but I gey invalid syntax on LIMIT?

Comment: @LewisElliott What SQL are you using? You are working with MySQL, right? @Exos Thanks, yes, `DESC` is needed to get the *top* 10.